# Simplify large Flow graph of decompiled android apk's function

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, android-security, ctf

I was attempting one CTF on mobile dev, While decompiling the apk to find the flag, I found that Jadx as well as JD-Gui was not able to decompile one class's function completely.
From AndroGuard Flow graph i realized that the class's function contain 30-40 if-else statements and some nested if-else statements too
The Flow graph is not so smooth and easy to analyze.

Is there any way by which we can decompile that class's function?
Or Is it possible to change the layout of flow graph to analyze the if-else statements more appropriately?